Switching from chakra UI to Panda CSS how to overrider a component styles
I'm currently working on a migration from Chakra UI to Panda CSS.
But I'm having a little trouble figuring out what to use between the various options offered by panda css to create a kind of simple component that I can override with style.
For example, let's say there's a card I want to change its width by overriding the default width. Which solution do you think works best?
I've tried to merge the style of a cva with css styles, but it seems very complicated for so little.
Thank you
